# Some limit questions around $1$

Tags: limits

1. Does $0.9 \times 0.99 \times 0.999 \times \dots$ have a limit, and if so, what?
2. Does $1 \times 1.01 \times 1.001 \times 1.0001 \times \dots$ have a limit and if so, what?

Comment: thought a lot. inspired by a recent post on k!^{1/k}. think 1 does, 2 doesn't. i tried applying Cantor's no largest number theorem. should i add this to the Q?

Comment: Hint: Sequence 1 is positive and decreasing.

Comment: mind u , i know 1 tends to a limit

Comment: Then what are you looking for, a proof of convergence?

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall; the limit in 1, both in 2

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, it is 1.11.. something. Try what I explained in the answer, you can find it! You have already found answer for 1, isn't it?

Comment: Also note that because of the nature of these infinite products you are not going to have a closed form. (e.g. the limit for 1 is 0.89001009999899900000001... There are many digits but the number is irrational and moreover transcendental; see http://wolfr.am/4cU3WkNq )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 1. It can also be written as $\prod\limits_{i}{(a_i)}=\prod\limits_{i}{(1-10^{-i})}$ - all numbers $0 < a_i < 1$, therefore it must stop somewhere between 0 and 1.

2. It can also be written as $\prod\limits_{i}{(1+10^{-i})}$

For both, write down and try multiplying first few terms, you can observe a generality, it will lead you to the limit!

Comment: not a proof that it converges, BWTH. Assuming this converges, and say prod(1.1^k) diverges, I was looking for the 'cut-off' point 'c' such that the 'variable' v v<c converges, v>=c v diverges (although the equality could be the other way round)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, can you explain it bit more clearly? Use \prod\limits_{lower}^upper for product (inside $)!

Comment: Lets say $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} f(x)\to a$ and $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} g(x)\to \infty$. Therefore between f() and g() there must be a function c() such that all functions x() < c() converge, and all functions x() >= c() diverge. It's a bit loose...